# Load X509 certificate from disk .Net Core

Tags: c#, ssl, https, .net-core, x509certificate

I've created an X509 certificate using OpenSSL. I am trying to load it using the Import method on the X509Certificate2 class, in .NET Core 2.0.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(_path);
```

But get thrown the following exception:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException : X509Certificate is immutable on this 
platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead.
```

Which constructor should I be using / what is the correct way to load this certificate from disk?

Comment: Have you tried new X509Certificate2(certificateAsByteArray), looking into the code of .net core import not implemented : https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/4617dd43596aabb0a109049dcea124fae5ba743e/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/src/System/Security/Cryptography/X509Certificates/X509Certificate2.cs

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(_path));
```

Comment: @user1034912 sorry to hear that. What runtime version do you use? Do you have the private key included in the PFX or is it ephemeral?